# Jquery stopwatch with milliseconds (accurate)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a stopwatch with miliseconds which is as accurate as possible.
Of course the browser/server/cpu or whatever will need more than 1 ms to execute the function and display the digit on the watch. So I thought i want to reset the ms to 0 each time a second goes up. 
jQuery code looks like this.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.stopwatch = function() {

        // The Element where the HTML code is added
        var clock = $(this);

        var timestamprunningms;
        var timestampstartms;

        var milliseconds = 0;
        // Predefinition of the timestamprunningseconds variable
        var timestamprunningseconds;

        var display = clock.find("#display");

        var time = clock.find("#time");

        // Predefinition of the seconds variable 
        // Value 0 because it is used to define
        // The timestampstartseconds variable in the click-event
        var seconds = 0;

        // Predefinition for the timestampstartseconds variable
        var timestampstartseconds;

        // Predefinition for the timer variable
        var timer;

        // Time Variables
        var h = clock.find("#h");
        var m = clock.find("#m");
        var s = clock.find("#s");
        var ms = clock.find("#ms");

        // Button Variables
        var resetlog = clock.find("#resetlog")
        var showms = clock.find("#showms")
        var hidems = clock.find("#hidems")
        var start = clock.find("#start");
        var pause = clock.find("#pause");
        var reset = clock.find("#reset");
        var log = clock.find("#log");

        ms.hide();
        resetlog.click(function (){
            time.html("");
        });

        // Hides the pause and hidems Button
        pause.hide();
        hidems.hide();
        // Triggered by clicking the start button
        start.click(function() {

            // Hides the start and shows the pause button
            start.hide(),
            pause.show(),

            // Defines the value of timestampstartseconds or saves it 
            // if there is a value in seconds
            timestampstartseconds = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) - seconds;
            timestampstartms = new Date().getTime() - milliseconds;
            timer = setInterval(do_time, 20);
        });

        // Triggered by clicking the pause button
        pause.click(function() {

            // Resets the interval in which the do_time function occurs
            clearInterval(timer),

            // Hides the pause and shows the start button
            pause.hide(),
            start.show(),
            timer = 0;
        });

        // Triggered by clicking the reset button
        reset.click(function() {

            // Resets the interval in which the do_time function occurs
            clearInterval(timer),

            // Resets the value of the display
            h.html("00"),
            m.html("00"),
            s.html("00"),
            ms.html("000")

            // Hides the pause and shows the start button
            pause.hide(),
            start.show();
            seconds = 0;


        });

        log.click(function() {
            time.append("<li>" + display.text() + "</li>");
        });
        // The function for calculating the seconds/minutes/hours

        showms.click(function() {
            showms.hide();
            hidems.show();
            ms.show();

        });

        hidems.click(function() {
            hidems.hide();
            showms.show();
            ms.hide();

        });
        function do_time() {

            // Timestamp that refreshes everytime the function is executed
            timestamprunningseconds = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
            timestamprunningms = new Date().getTime();
            // The actual seconds that are going to be displayed
            milliseconds = timestamprunningms - timestampstartms;
            seconds = timestamprunningseconds - timestampstartseconds;

            // Value of the display
            var hour = parseFloat(h.text());
            var minute = parseFloat(m.text());
                if (milliseconds > 999) {
                    milliseconds = 0;
                    timestampstartms = new Date().getTime();
                }

                // Reset seconds display and add a minute every time 60 seconds pass
                if (seconds > 59) {
                    seconds = 0;
                    timestampstartseconds = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
                    minute++;

                }

                // Reset minute display and add an hour every time 60 minutes pass
                if (minute > 59) {
                    minute = 0;
                    hour++;

                }

                // Display value
                 h.html("0".substring(hour >= 10) + hour);
                 m.html("0".substring(minute >= 10) + minute);
                 s.html("0".substring(seconds >= 10) + seconds.toString());
                 ms.html(":" + "0".substring(milliseconds >= 100) +"0".substring(milliseconds >= 10) + milliseconds.toString());
            };
        };

})(jQuery);
```

As I already said, my goal is to reset the millisecond timer every time a second goes up. (the seconds are accurate, the milliseconds aren't).

would that be something like this?:

```
while (seconds++) {
                    milliseconds = 0;
                    timestampstartms = new Date().getTime();
                }
```

I'm really new to javascript/jQuery and programming in general so it would be very nice if you could help me with this problem and maybe give a little feedback so I can improve.

Comment: Have you tried the code you posted, where you said "Would that be something like this"? Did you get unexpected results? What were they?

Comment: Be careful with JavaScript timing. Because JS is single threaded (in the browser), you can't count on setInterval, etc. callbacks executing at the exact time specified. Rather, the interval is the minimum interval between invocations.

Comment: @Paulpro yes I tried it with :`while (seconds++) {
                    milliseconds = 0;
                    timestampstartms = new Date().getTime();
                }`, but the site crashes after about 1.5 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution: i just added a variable which is like a timestamp of the current second. It has a default value of 0 and goes 1 up if the seconds that is used in the display is greater than the second timestamp.

looks a bit like this: `var secondnow = 0;` (on top of the jQuery function)

and this is how it's used

```
if (seconds > secondnow) {
                    milliseconds = 0;
                    secondnow++;
                    timestampstartms = new Date().getTime();
                    console.log(secondnow);
                }
```

(in the function do_time)